# Skype4COM C++ event handling

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, skype4com

Could anyone provide working example in C++ with event handling for Skype4COM, i.e. incoming call or incoming message handling?

I use "IDispEventImpl" to catch events, but it gives an error when event occurs:
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location "0x00000014".

It seems that some variable not initialized:
in atlcore.h:
in CComCriticalSection class:
in HRESULT Lock():
EnterCriticalSection(&m_sec);

Here is link to project: 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41844149/SkypeCallbackExample.zip

What is wrong?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Please only post questions with specific problems, not general "do this for me" requests.

Comment: I can't understand how to hook specific function to specific event in c++ (Visual studio 2010). Tried __hook(), but it won't compile.

Comment: I could'n find a single example in c++ how to use Skype4COM events. Could anyone help, post here a link where it could be found? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found code example here: 
[COM event handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/TEventHandler.aspx?fid=133954&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=None&select=2755820#xx2755820xx)

Source code that is based on example and uses Skype4COM and shows messagebox when anyone calls you on Skype is here: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41844149/TEventHandler.rar)

Thank you.